# Python web scraping using BeautifulSoup, how to merge two <p> text into one element of list

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I use BeautifulSoup to do the web scraping, the put the result into a list, 
html shows like this:

```html
<p class="attrgroup">
            <span><b>2013 Volkswagen Passat</b></span>
            <br>
    </p>
<p class="attrgroup">
            <span>condition: <b>excellent</b></span>
            <br>
    </p>
```

my code is:

```
title=[]
text=[]
for newpage in list:
webpage = urlopen(newpage).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage,'html.parser')
header=soup.find_all("span",attrs={"id":"titletextonly"})
info = soup.find_all("p",attrs={"class":"attrgroup"})
for h in header:
        title.append(h.get_text())
for m in info:
        text.append(m.get_text())
```

the text list result is:
 ["2013 Volkswagen Passat","condition:excellent"]

But i want the result like this:
 ["2013 Volkswagen Passat  condition:excellent"]

How to merge the two text when put into a list? please help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `join()` function of lists.

```
title = []
for h in header:
        title.append(h.get_text())
title = ''.join([title])
```

Else, add elements to the list instead of text and use `list comprehension` to join texts.

```
title = []
for h in header:
        title.append(h)
title = ''.join([i.text for i in title])
```

Hope this helps! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

you can use stripped_strings

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html = """<p class="attrgroup">
        <span><b>2013 Volkswagen Passat</b></span>
        <br>
      </p>
      <p class="attrgroup">
        <span>condition: <b>excellent</b></span>
        <br>
</p>"""

tag = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

data = (' '.join(tag.stripped_strings))
print data
```